# Javascript dynamic by id in ajax php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, ajax

im not understand what this case's name, i have php with ajax and bootstrap css to get content from another page dynamically by using value but i show it inside of foreach.
this is my code

```
<?php foreach($a as $b){?>
  <button onclick="showUser(this.value)" value="<?php echo $b->p_slug;?>">View Detail</button>
<?php }?> 

<div id="txtHint"></div>
```

my Ajax script

```
<script>
function showUser(str) {
  if (str=="") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    return;
  }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","<?php echo base_url('testing');?>/"+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

From that php it display a lot of product list inline,and if i click that button it showing result of data (work well)
 but the problem is, i want to display that data response in bellow of button that i have clicked

For example, if i click (red square), content will display in bellow of button, and other list "view detail" bellow will moving down.

[image]

Thankyou

Comment: $a->p_slug is unique?

Comment: Yes unique from database

Comment: $a->p_slug should be $b->p_slug.

Comment: sorry, typo in here, but it not the problem. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your html you could echo your div next to your button (you might need some css here to keep your html from rendering in a weird way when you click the button):

```
<?php foreach($a as $b){?>
  <button onclick="showUser(this.value,<?php echo $b->p_slug ?>)" value="<?php echo $a->p_slug;?>">View Detail</button>
  <div id="txthint<?php echo $b->p_slug ?>"></div>
<?php }?>
```

Then edit your script to use the new id's for your divs:

```
<script>
function showUser(str,slug) {
  if (str=="") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint" + slug).innerHTML="";
    return;
  }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("txtHint" + slug).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","<?php echo base_url('testing');?>/"+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for anwer, i try but show error
ReferenceError: slug is not defined
 

document.getElementById("txtHint" + slug).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

Comment: did you include it in your function header? "function showUser(str,slug)"

Comment: Update, new error TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
 

document.getElementById("txtHint" + slug).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

Comment: check the html it generated and see what the id for the divs is like

Comment: i update to document.getElementById("txtHint"+str).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; and working fine, great awesome, thankyou mate

Comment: @AlanEl-ninoMalmsteen make sure to also check ArchiT3k's answer to hide and show the div every time you click another one

Comment: also I guess $b->p_slug is the same as str then? otherwise it shouldn't work, ah I see now, it is

Answer (score 0):

Ok.

You have to put a div in your HTML. 
Right after each ViewMore element,
and make it visible (css visible, or jQuery show() ) when you have clicked it.

Yep... instead of one only #txthint, make several div like

```
 <div class="txthint" id="4(or whatever you want)">...</div>
 <div class="txthint" id="5(or whatever you want)">...</div>
 <div class="txthint" id="6(or whatever you want)">...</div>
 <div class="txthint" id="7(or whatever you want)">...</div>
```

...

In your script :

```
 <script>
//init first - hide all
document.getElementsByClass("txtHint").style.display="none";

    //function
function showUser(str) {
      if (str=="") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
        return;
      }
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {


           //document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    document.getElementById("4orwhateveryouwant").innerHtml=xml...(idem);
    **

    //here is it !
        //1. hide all
    document.getElementsByClass("txtHint").style.display="none";
    //2. show clicked
    document.getElementById("4orwhateveryouwant").style.display="block";
            }

**
      }
      xmlhttp.open("GET","<?php echo base_url('testing');?>/"+str,true);
      xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: i try to use hide all display error TypeError: document.getElementByClasses is not a function
 

document.getElementByClasses("txtHint").style.display="none";

Comment: sorry : use getElementsByClass ( i ve edited)  //// frankly, I would use jQuery for such a work. Quicker faster.

Comment: i try to fix your code but no result, still display an error TypeError: document.getElementsByClass is not a function
 

document.getElementsByClass("box").style.display="none";

Comment: it multiple class for box cz i use foreach php in that html